# Bayes' Theorem Solution Verification

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

> An insurance company examines its pool of auto insurance customers and gathers the following information:
>
> All customers insure at least one car
>
> $64\%$ of the customers insure more than one car.
>
> $20\%$ of the customers insure a sports car.
>
> Of those customers who insure more than one car, $15\%$ insure a sports car.
>
> What is the probability that a randomly selected customer insures exactly one car and that car is not a sports car?

**My attempt**:
Let $S$ denote the event that a policyholder insures a sports car. Let $X$ denote the number of cars insured. We need to find $P(\{X = 1\}\cap S')$. Note that
$$P(\{X = 1\}\cap S') = P(\{X = 1\}| S')\cdot P(S') = [1-P(\{X = 1\}| S)]\cdot (1-0.2) = [1-P(\{X = 1\}| S)]\cdot 0.8$$

Also, $0.2 = [P(S|X=1) \cdot 0.36] + [0.64 \cdot 0.15] \implies P(S|X=1) \approx 0.289$

Using Bayes' Theorem, $P(\{X = 1\}| S) = \dfrac{P(S|X=1) \cdot P(X=1)}{P(S|X=1) \cdot P(X=1) + P(S|X>1) \cdot P(X>1)} = \dfrac{0.289 \cdot 0.36}{(0.289 \cdot 0.36) + (0.15 \cdot 0.64)} \approx 0.52$.

Therefore, $P(\{X = 1\}\cap S') = [1-0.52] \cdot 0.8 \approx 0.384$, which is not correct. Can someone please let me know where I went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=$"insures more than a car"

$B=$"insures a sport car"

We are asked to get
$$P(\bar A \cap \bar B)=P(\overline{A\cup B})=1-P(A\cup B)$$

We obtain
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=0,64+0,20-P(A\cap B)$$

We need
$$P(B/A)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\implies P(A\cap B)=P(B/A)P(A)=0,15\cdot 0,64 =0,096$$

So, finally

$$P(\bar A \cap \bar B)=1-P(A\cup B)=1-(0,64+0,20-P(A\cap B))=1-(0,64+0,20-0,096).$$

That is

$$P(\bar A \cap \bar B)=1-(0,64+0,20-0,096)=0,256.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please point out what I did incorrectly?

Comment: Can you prove $P(\{X = 1\}| S') = [1-P(\{X = 1\}| S)]$? In general, is it $P(A/\bar B)=1-P(A/B)?$

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I found this rule in the first response to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948766/what-is-the-complement-of-conditional-probabilities

Comment: I think you have the following problem: $P(\bar A/B)=1-P(A/B)$ which is completely different from $P(A/\bar B)=1-P(A/B)$

Comment: I mean, the first equality holds independently of $A, B$ but the second one doesn't

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks so much! I would have kept making using the incorrect version of this rule if you wouldn't have pointed that out! I think the broader idea is that you can never flip the condition that is given.

Comment: Yes. You got the point. You're welcome.