# Probability of A given B complement

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

In this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948766/what-is-the-complement-of-conditional-probabilities) it is laid out the following identity.
$$
    P(A|B^c) = 1 - P(A^c|B^c)
$$
Been trying to prove it without success. I can only prove that
$$
1-P(A^c|B^c) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B^c)}
$$
so I'm starting to think that identity on the other question is wrong. Can anyone help me prove if the first identity is true?

Edit: my result explanation

$$
1 - P(A^c|B^c) = 1 - \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}
$$
$$
1 - \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}=1- \frac{1-P(A)-P(B)}{P(B^c)}=1-(\frac{1-P(B)}{P(B^c)} - \frac{P(A)}{P(B^C)}) = 1-(1-\frac{P(A)}{P(B^c)})= \frac{P(A)}{P(B^c)}
$$

Comment: $1 - \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}=1- \frac{1-P(A)-P(B)}{P(B^c)}$ is not generally correct

Comment: In which cases is not correct? Even if A  and B represent the whole universe of possibilities it can still apply isn't it? in that case it would be $1 - P(A) - P(B) = 1 - 1 = 0$

Comment: To take a simple example if $P(A)=P(B)=\frac12$ and they are independent so $P(A^c \cap B^c)=\frac14$, then $1 - \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}= 1-\frac{\frac14}{1/2}=\frac12$ while $1- \frac{1-P(A)-P(B)}{P(B^c)}=1-\frac{1-\frac12-\frac12}{1/2}=1$

Comment: I see my error now... the general identity is $P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B)$ that last intersection must be summed otherwise you would be subtracting it twice. Accepting your answer since you laid out the algebraic work, but other answers are excellent too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A\mid B^c)$

$=\dfrac{P(A, B^c)}{P(B^c)}$

$=\dfrac{P(B^c) - P(A^c, B^c)}{P(B^c)}$

$=\dfrac{P(B^c)}{P(B^c)}-\dfrac{P(A^c, B^c)}{P(B^c)}$

$=1- P(A^c\mid B^c)$

Answer (score 4):

$P(A|B^C)+P(A^C|B^C)=1$ because both cases are incompatible, and if you know $B^C$ to be true, either $A$ happens or $A^C$ happens, which gives it a probability of 1.

Comment: Is there anyway to arrive at this algebraically? Also, is my own result correct though? I have edited with my algebraic process. If it is correct, then is it really the case that $P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(A)}{P(B^c)}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Rhizome's answer is clear enough, but here is a diagram to show it:

[image]

Since $A$ and $A'$ are the only two possibilities for event $A$, $P(A | B') + P(A' | B') = P(B' | B') = 1$ by the law of total probability.

Answer (score 1):

$A \cup B=(A\setminus B) \cup B$ and $P(A \cup B)=P(A\setminus B)+P(B)$. This gives $1-P(A^{c}\cap B^{c})=P(A\setminus B)+P(B)$ or $1-P(B)+P(A^{c}\cap B^{c})=P(A\setminus B)$. Divide throughout by $1-P(B)$. Can you finish?